# How to solve CollectionViewcell image animation images issue?

Tags: imageview, collectionview, swift5

> I have set an animated image in CollectionView cell but I
>   didSelectItemAt method call but how can solve animated image this hide
>   issue please see this [video URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqgOl.gif).

```
let data:[UIImage] = images![indexPath.row] as! [UIImage]
cell.ivImage.animationImages = data
cell.ivImage.animationDuration = 1.0
cell.ivImage.startAnimating()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stickerCV.allowsSelection = false
```

**Collection Cell**

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
            tap.accessibilityLabel = "\(indexPath.row),\(indexPath.section)"
            tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            cell.ivSitcker.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            cell.ivSitcker.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

**Tap Gesture**

```
@objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let data = sender.accessibilityLabel?.components(separatedBy: ",")
    let index = Int(data![0])
    let section = Int(data![1])
    selectedIndex = index!
    let sectionData = AppData.sharedInstance.arrOfStickers[selectedStickerIndex]
    self.strSelectedSticker = sectionData[index!]
    self.createSticker(image: self.strSelectedSticker[0])
    self.selectedIndex = index!
    self.stickerCV.reloadData()
}
```